# Help required on onbeforeunload or click on browser back button

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

If a user clicks the browser's back button, then I want a prompt to appear and ask for confirmation. If the user clicks 'OK', then it should navigate to `xx.html`. If the user clicks 'Cancel', then it should prevent the navigation.  How can I do this?

Note: Already I tried the `onbeforeunload` method, but it is working for all the navigation actions.  For Example, clicking the link on the page will also fire this event and show the message to the user.

Comment: Check this URL might help you http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The best you can do is use `onbeforeunload` and remove that event when clicking on a normal link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "Are you sure?"}
</script>

<a href="somewhere.html" onclick="window.onbeforeunload = null;">Leave</a>
```

Comment: Note: as mentioned in my answer, you may need to handle `<form>` submissions too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is helped to control other events in the page. But i am unable to catch whether user clicked "OK" in the dialog box which onbeforeunload method provides. Because if  user clicks OK then i need to navigate the user to specific page. Please provide any code snippet. It will be helpful.

Comment: @Bala: That is not possible. Rule of thumb for web apps: if you think need to rely on events such as `on(before)unload` or try to control where the user navigates to (including controlling the back/forward buttons), then your whole concept is broken. Your concept needs to embrace the features of the web (and browsers) not work against it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to differentiate between navigational actions in the `onbeforeunload` event.  You *could* disable it for all links/forms on the page by removing the `window.onbeforeunload` handler in each link's `onclick` handler, or `onsubmit` for forms.  However, you will still be unable to tell whether the user clicked back, forward, a bookmark, etc or typed a new address into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to capture the "beforeunload" event (which previous answers here did).

```
// Display browser warning message when back/forward/reload or hyperlink navigation occurs
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
  console.log('page navigation captured');
  return 'By leaving this page you will lose the data you have entered here.';
});
```

More importantly, you want to allow non-disrupted navigation from certain elements (e.g. links with class "allow-navigation"). The way to achieve is to remove the event-handler when your links of choice are clicked.

```
// Disable capture for certain elements
$('.allow-navigation').on('click', function(e) {
    $(window).off('beforeunload');
    console.log('page navigation allowed');
});
```

Will work for your links of the type:

```
<a href="#" class="allow-navigation">Click me</a>
```

This way you can control the page navigation. Browser back/forward/etc still open the confirmation box. But the links you choose will work without any disruption.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

> you can do this
>
> ```
> $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
>     return "Are you Sure you want to leave this page?"; // Return whatever message you want
> });​
> ```
>
> also if xx.html is the page in their history than you dont need to add
>   anything just return a message it will automatically put buttons for
>   you
>
> Edit: see fiddle before you assume it does not answer the question
>   asked http://jsfiddle.net/Lxq93/
>
> Edit: there is no definitive way to display a message only on the back
>   button in my knowledge i have also looked and have seen the only
>   methods that pick up on the back button  are
>   `$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(){return;})` and
>   `$(window).onbeforeunload = function(){return;}` and they both pick up
>   on when the page is refreshed or any other navigation away from the
>   current page. This is currently the best answer that can be provided
>   in the year 2014

Edit:

above is for all unload events

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhw2x/85/

been messing with that through all its lower objects it cant be done through javascript till someone decides to make all major browsers use a specific name for each unload event instead of it just being an unload event

so the answer is no you cannot force a navigation to a specific page when they click okay on the confirmation when they try to go to a different page

and back button does not have a specific event name it shares its event with several different events all in the unload event so you cannot make a back button specific function through javascript