# Is it possible to prevent changing of router by clicking back button?

Tags: backbone.js, single-page-application, router, backbone-routing

I'am building single page using BackboneJS and I need to prevent router executing on back button in a browser. To be exact I need to show confirmation custom popup with the text "Do you really want exit room? [yes|no]". So if user clicks `yes` then default actions should happens but if `no` then user should stay in the current screen.

I use `Backbone.router` with `pushState: true`. Does Backbonejs provide something like `before` router event to be possible prevent router handling or how could I archive it?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184521/help-required-on-onbeforeunload-or-click-on-browser-back-button

Comment: This is not duplicate of because I need to just show custom popup on any route changing with no difference whether on onbeforeunload or click on browser back button

Comment: sorry, seems like I misunderstood. Please see my answer about a possible way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still an issue, but this is how I would get around it. It may not be the best way, but could be a step in the right direction.

```
Backbone.History.prototype.loadUrl = function (fragment, options) {
    var result = true;
    if (fragment === void (0) && options === void (0) && this.confirmationDisplay !== void(0))
    {
        result = confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this room?');
    }
    var opts = options;
    fragment = Backbone.history.fragment = Backbone.history.getFragment(fragment);
    if (result) {
        this.confirmationDisplay = true;
        return _.any(Backbone.history.handlers, function (handler) {
            if (handler.route.test(fragment)) {
                //We just pass in the options
                handler.callback(fragment, opts);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    return this;
}
```

Essentially checking if we have a fragment and options, if not, we can assume the app just started, or the user clicked the back button.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you suggest solution without overriding of internal Backbone API?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone router has an execute method which is called for every route change, we can return false to prevent the current transition. The code will probably look like below :

With an asynchronous popup (untested code, but should work)

```
Backbone.Route.extend({
  execute: function(callback,args){
    if(this.lastRoute === 'room'){
      showPopup().done(function(){
         callback & callback.apply(this,args);
       }).fail(function(){
         Backbone.history.navigate('room/486',{trigger:false});
      });
    }else{
      callback && callback.apply(this,args);
    }
  },
  showPopup: function(){
    var html = "<<div><p>Do you really want to exit</p><button id='yes'>Yes</button><button id='no'>No</button></div>"
    var promise = $.Deferred();
    $('body').append(html);
    $(document).on('click','button#yes',function(){
      promise.resolve();
    });
    $(document).on('click','button#no',function(){
      promise.reject();
    });
    return promise;
  }
});
```

With synchronous confirm popup

```
Backbone.Route.extend({
  execute: function(callback,args){
    if(this.lastRoute === 'room'){
      var conf = confirm("Do you really want to exit the room ?");
      if(!conf){
        //Change the route back to room
        Backbone.history.navigate('room/486',{trigger:false});
        return false;
      }
    };
    callback && callback.apply(this,args);
  }
});
```

References:

http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute

Comment: Thanks for the solution I've thought about it but by my problem is I need to show custom popup (like jQuery popup) which is not asynchronous. So your code is partial solution for my question